# Derived member object in a derived class

Tags: c#, oop

I have the following classes:

```
public class A {
    public C mObj:
}

public class B : A {
}

public class C {
    public int val1;
}

public class D : C {
    public int val2;
}
```

I initialize all the class B instances in a way that `inst.mObj = new D();`. When I have an instance of class B I would ideally like to access all the members of class D by using `mObj`, but due to inheritance I can not do it without casting into D first.

I would like class B to have a member object of class D, but I automatically inherit a member from class C. Is there a way to achieve something like that? If not then how is it usually done when a similar structure is required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is difficult to determine your exact requirements, but you could try to use [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) with type [constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

```
public class A<T>
    where T : C
{
    public T mObj:
}

public class B : A<D> 
{
}

public class C 
{
    public int val1;
}

public class D : C 
{
    public int val2;
}
```

In this case the `mObj` in `B` will be of type `D`, so no conversion will be required.